# playwright Error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: waiting for firstPage Proxy failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded

Tags: javascript, playwright

```
const playwright = require("playwright");

(async () => {
  for (const browserType of ["chromium", "firefox", "webkit"]) {
    const browser = await playwright[browserType].launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage('https://google.com/');
     await page.screenshot({ path: `example-${browserType}.png` });

  }
})();
```

I have tried to run this snippet. It takes a screenshot from chromium and firefox as expected. but it throws a timeout error when it tries to take a screenshot from webkit. although, local-webkit is installed with playwright.

Comment: Which OS and Node version are you using?

Comment: Please file a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/new/choose and help us with info about your environment. We get this error when local webkit is found, but does not communicate with us. See what executable is saying via `playwright[browserType].launch({ dumpio: true })`? Also, see if it runs for you via `./node_modules/playwright-core/.local-webkit/mac-1127/pw_run.sh`.